# C - как создать несколько структур в цикле?

Tags: c

Можно в C в цикле создать несколько структур, например 10? Как без цилка - это понятно. Можно ли в цикле как-то создать структуры st2, st3,st4.... Массивы символов можно заполнить дефолтными значениями, например 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(){
    typedef struct worker{
        char fio[100];
        char staff[200];
        int year;
    } worker;
    
  worker st1 = {"PETROV", "ingineer", 2000};

    printf("%s %s %d \n", st1.fio, st1.staff, st1.year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: создаёте массив структур `worker arr[10];` обращение по индексу `arr[5].year = 2021 ;`

Comment: *нужен malloc?* : На ваше усмотрение. Если маленький размер массива и он нужен только локально, то можно держать его в стеке `worker arr[10];`. А если большой или его нужно создать и передать в удалённый участок кода *(что выше по стеку)* то передавайте указатель `malloc(sizeof(worker)*10)`

Comment: А можете пояснить что значит - WORKER *base = malloc(itter * sizeof *base); ? Мы определяем размер и присваиваем его значение переменной base c типом WORKER?